# What's the syntax for otherwise in XSLT if we have to update the value for an existing key/element

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am trying to add a new key in a CustomAPI Node using Choose when. If new key doesn't present in existing node, it is adding a key. So, a new key is adding to node. So, to update the value of existing key, while using otherwise I am unable to change value of a existing key in a node.
We implemented those using following code. Also find the error attached after this code.

XML Input:-

```
<Configuration>
  <CustomAPI>
    <add key="City" value="Mumbai"/>
    <add key="Street" value="Dalal"/>   
  </CustomAPI>
</Configuration>
```

XSLT:-

```
 <xsl:template match="/configuration/CustomAPI">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(add[@key = 'City'])">
            <add key="City" value="Mumbai"/>
        </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:template match="/configuration/CustomAPI/add[@key='City']/@value">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">Delhi</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:otherwise>                
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

XML Output:-

```
 <Configuration>
   <CustomAPI>
    <add key="City" value="Delhi"/>
    <add key="Street" value="Dalal"/>   
   </CustomAPI>
 </Configuration>
```

Error:-
"'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:otherwise' element."

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your `xsl:otherwise` block? You have an `xsl:template` inside of an `xsl:template`, which is what the error is about. Are you attempting to generate an XSLT stylesheet? Maybe post the desired output or provide a little more explanation of what you are *attempting* to do.

Comment: @MadsHansen
First of all my agenda is to change values in Web.config using XSLT transformation. I wrote this complete code in a web.config.xslt and executing through Powershell script. So, while I am using the syntax for 'When', the key is being added to existing node. So, again to update the value in existing key, I used that syntax in otherwise. That will check for existing key in node and then will update value for key if it was written in outside of 'Choose' node. Then I used that syntax in 'Otherwise' but it failed. So, is there any other syntax for otherwise to achieve my need.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example of the input XML and the expected result.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, Please find the example in following link:-   https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Wtyamk8DQDOOnGFl56KX6ZFFGuhKwEM/view?usp=sharing

And suggest a suitable syntax for 'Otherwise' to achieve our result.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code within your  question and add an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Edited the subject according to requirement. And suggest a suitable syntax for 'Otherwise' to achieve our output

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow your logic. The input has the city of Mumbai. Why is it necessary to replace it with Delhi?

Comment: @michael.hor257k
Take that Delhi as a variable, while developing developer wants to update that variable according to his requirement. So instead of updating complete file, he updates that particular key's value using xslt in xml by xpath

Comment: I am afraid I still don't get it. I suggest you edit your question and add a simple step-by-step  explanation how would one modify the input if performing the modifications manually.